# Overline and subscripts interfere with the fraction horizontal rule if I use small text

Tags: equations, fractions

I am trying to typeset headings in a small tabular environment.

I get interference with the horizontal rule in the fractional sign.  I managed to fix it in a crude way.

Is there a better solution?  Is there a way to typeset an equation style in running text?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\eff{\ensuremath{\mathrm{eff}}}

\begin{document}
{\small% I use small for my table
To solve the vertical spacing in\\
$F=\frac{A_\eff}{\overline{|A|}}$\\
I tried\\
$F=\frac{A_\eff\vphantom{_y}}{\overline{|A|}}$\\
to solve the subscript and\\
$F=\frac{A_\eff}{\overline{|A|}\vphantom{~\int}}$\\
to solve the overline giving
$F=\frac{A_\eff\vphantom{_y}}{\overline{|A|}\vphantom{~\int}}$.

Is there a easier way to get it closer to:
\begin{equation}
    F=\frac{A_\eff}{\overline{|A|}}?
\end{equation}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\newcommand*{\eff}{\mathrm{eff}}` (forget about `\ensuremath`) and `$\displaystyle F=\frac{A_{\eff}}{\overline{|A|}}$`? Or possibly no `\displaystyle`, but `amsmath`'s `\dfrac` instead? Or if you want to keep a small typeface: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*{\eff}{\mathrm{eff}}

\begin{document}

\small $F=\frac{\smash[t]{\strut} A_{\eff}}{\smash[b]{\strut} \overline{|A|}}$

\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference between your last equation and those that precede it, is that the last one is a *display formula*, whereas the other ones are *inline formulas*. Display formulas are implicitly typeset in `\displaystyle`, whereas inline ones use `\textstyle`. A fraction occurring in display style has its numerators and denominators typeset in text style, while a fraction occurring in text style has its numerators and denominators in script style (cramped variants of the styles for the denominators: exponents aren't raised as much as in non-cramped styles). This is explained in the TeXbook pp. 140-141.

So, if you want the inline equation to look like the last one, the easiest way is to typeset it in `\displaystyle` by issuing this command at the beginning of the corresponding math formula:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\eff}{\mathrm{eff}}

\begin{document}

{\small
  Inline formula using \verb|\displaystyle|:
  $\displaystyle F=\frac{A_{\eff}}{\overline{|A|}}$.

  Display formula:
  \begin{equation}
    F=\frac{A_{\eff}}{\overline{|A|}}.
  \end{equation}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want `\displaystyle` to affect many inline formulas at once (after having weighed the pros and the cons), you can use `{\everymath{\displaystyle} ... }` with the formulas in the `...`.

Another, more local technique, to have fractions in `\displaystyle` is to use `amsmath`'s `\dfrac` command:

```latex
\usepackage{amsmath}

...

$F=\dfrac{A_{\eff}}{\overline{|A|}}$
```

Note that I removed the use of `\ensuremath`, because it doesn't help to keep a tidy source where it is always clear if something is to be used in text or in math mode. Also, better use `\frac{A_{\eff}}{...}` than `\frac{A_\eff}{...}`. Depending on the expansion of `\eff`, I believe the latter could give bad surprises.

Another rather different way to format your fraction, adding vertical space where you wanted it, but keeping the numerator and denominator in script style, is to insert struts to add height or depth where you want. Here, I use `amsmath`'s `\smash[t]{...}` to “kill” the top part of a `\strut`, and `\smash[b]{...}` to “kill” its bottom part.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*{\eff}{\mathrm{eff}}

\begin{document}

{\small
  Inline formula using \verb|\textstyle|:
  $F=\frac{\smash[t]{\strut} A_{\eff}}{\smash[b]{\strut} \overline{|A|}}$.

  Display formula:
  \begin{equation}
    F=\frac{A_{\eff}}{\overline{|A|}}.
  \end{equation}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]